# Warning message while kriging in R

Tags: r, kriging, gstat

```
krig_Gaussian<-krige(formula=(B)~1, locations=Amb_m, newdata=gd_m, model=model_Gaussian.variog_m)
[using ordinary kriging]
Warning messages:
1: In proj4string(d$data) :
  CRS object has comment, which is lost in output
2: In proj4string(newdata) :
  CRS object has comment, which is lost in output
3: In proj4string(newdata) :
  CRS object has comment, which is lost in output
```

This is my code. Can someone help me on this?

```
#variogram
Boron.var_m <- variogram(log(B)~1, Amb_m)
plot(Boron.var_m)

#models
model_Gaussian.variog_m<-vgm(psill=1.35, model="Gau", nugget=1, range=0.065)

fit.variog6_m<-fit.variogram(Boron.var_m, model_Gaussian.variog_m)
plot(Boron.var_m, fit.variog6_m)

krig_Gaussian<-krige(formula=(B)~1, locations=Amb_m, newdata=gd_m, model=model_Gaussian.variog_m)
```

where `Amb_m` is spatialpointdataframe, `gd_m` is the grid for newdata, `B` is the observations on boron samples.

Comment: It means nothing, just a quirk associated with the transition to the new WKT projection format in GDAL/PROJ the warning actually originates from rgdal. Althoug, please always add the packages that you are working with.

Comment: Could you please give some clarification